# Como copiar um arquivo da rede para o meu computador usando C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, arquivo, redes

Tenho uma aplicação desktop que precisa copiar arquivos de mídia de um servidor, vídeos e imagens. O servidor está na mesma rede do terminal no qual estará instalado o programa. O problema é, que este terminal não estará logado com usuário e senha na rede, terei de passar um *user* e uma senha para ele para poder trabalhar com os arquivos, porém não achei como fazer isso.

Minha implementação abaixo opera perfeitamente no meu PC, onde estou logado com usuário de rede e a minha senha, ele vai busca os arquivos no servidor e os coloca no caminho no meu computador. Porém quando rodo ele no terminal que deverá ficar rodando os vídeos e imagens ele diz que o sistema não tem permissão de acesso.

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                string[] directoryes = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (string directoriePath in directoryes)
                {
                    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoriePath);

                    if (files.Count() != 0)
                    {
                        // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
                        foreach (string s in files)
                        {
                            // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                            System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
            }
```

Como posso fazer para primeiro me logar com usuário e senha no servidor e buscar estes arquivos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma solução é usar a [classe `Impersonator` disponível no CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User).

Também tem [respostas boas (a aceita e mais votada) no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295538/221800). Usaram [`WNetAddConnection2`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) da API do Windows para conseguir isto. Parece ser a solução mais seguida, com variações de implementações. [Outra pergunta possui implementações alternativas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/659013/221800).

Comment: Valeu, vou dar uma olhada e testar amanhã pela manhã.